# How to pass the values of an array of objects to another one properly in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

So i am trying to make a phonebook right now, and one of my tasks was to read the informations of the people in a text file.
As i call the function in my main.cpp, my array of objects does not get the data from the text file. I made a scratch.cpp to test the method i am trying to use, and it works, but as soon as i try to use it in my program, it doesn't work properly.

I made a scratch.cpp to test the method i am trying to use, and it works, but as soon as i try to use it in my program, it doesn't work properly.

This is supposed to change the value of an array

```
void TxtReader::read(Contacts* &contacts){
    Contacts *contacts2 = new Contacts[0];
    int contactSize = 0;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string birthPlace;
    std::string birthDate;
    std::string Profession;
    std::ifstream savedContacts("ContactList.txt");
    Contacts newContact = Contacts();
    do {
        std::getline(savedContacts, firstName, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, lastName, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, phoneNumber, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, birthPlace, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, birthDate, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, Profession, ';');
        newContact.setFirstname(firstName);
        newContact.setLastname(lastName);
        newContact.setPhonenumber(phoneNumber);
        newContact.setBirthplace(birthPlace);
        newContact.setBirthdate(birthDate);
        newContact.setProfession(Profession);
        pushContact(contacts2, newContact, contactSize);
    } while (std::getline(savedContacts, firstName));
    delete[] contacts;
    contacts = contacts2;
    delete[] contacts2;
}
```

and here is how i called it in another class

```
void ContactDir::getList() {
    textReader.read(contacts);
}
```

and then i used this in my main.cpp

Everything seemed fine for me, the program can be compiled, but it crashes as it gets to the getList function.

The debugger shows multiple errors like :
 "this = -var-create: unable to create variable object" in the main,
and "Signal = SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)" in the TxtReader::read function and in Contacts class. and also i got errors like 
"   firstName = (std::_cxx11::string)""  " in contacts and contacts2 and newContact objects

The Contacts class has setters and getters like this:

```
Contacts::Contacts() {}

void Contacts::setFirstname(std::string firstName) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
}

std::string Contacts::getFirstname() {
    return firstName;
}
```

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. For instance: what is `pushContact`? 2) Why `Contacts *contacts2 = new Contacts[0];` instead of `std::vector<Contacts> contacts2;`? 3) How was `contacts` allocated?

Comment: Consider using an echo-of-input in your 'TextReader::read()',  start with echoing the firstName right after the "std::getline(savedContacts, firstName, ';');  fills it.  Simply append a cout statement to the line.  Run the program and if it lists all or most of the names, move the line down to the next getline...repeat.  "echo-of-input" is a debug technique that is simple and (re)moveable.  (and ancient)  Objective: prove  input is happening,  Can you guess the next step?

Comment: pushContact increases the size of the array by one and adds a value to that +1
@AlgirdasPreidžius

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is two-fold. First this:

```
Contacts *contacts2 = new Contacts[0];
```

That's a zero-size allocation. You cannot store anything into `contacts2` since it has a size of zero.

But even if its size wasn't zero, you also have this:

```
contacts = contacts2;
delete[] contacts2;
```

`contacts` points to `contacts2`, which you delete, so `contacts` points to deleted memory. So either don't delete `contacts2`, or (much better) do not use `new` and do not use `delete`. Instead, use `std::vector` to store your objects. For example your `read()` function could take a reference to a vector of `Contacts`:

```
void TxtReader::read(std::vector<Contacts>& contacts);
```

And your temporary objects would be vectors as well:

```
std::vector<Contacts> contacts2;
```

The assignment:

contacts = contacts2;

will then work as intended, since it will copy the objects.